# how to move the view up when keyboard is showing using react-native

Tags: react-native

native-keyboardevents for move the view up when keyboard is showing,  i wrote my code like this

```
var KeyboardEvents = require('react-native-keyboardevents');
var KeyboardEventEmitter = KeyboardEvents.Emitter;
class Account extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      keyboardSpace: 0,
      isKeyboardOpened: false
    };
  }
  updateKeyboardSpace(frames){
    this.setState({
      keyboardSpace: frames.end.height,
      isKeyboardOpened: true
    });
  }
  resetKeyboardSpace(){
    this.setState({
      keyboardSpace: 0,
      isKeyboardOpened: false
    });
  }
  componentDidMout(){
    KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardDidShowEvent, this.updateKeyboardSpace);
    KeyboardEventEmitter.on(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardWillHideEvent, this.resetKeyboardSpace);
  }
  componentWillunmount(){
    KeyboardEventEmitter.off(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardDidShowEvent, this.updateKeyboardSpace);
    KeyboardEventEmitter.off(KeyboardEvents.KeyboardWillHideEvent, this.resetKeyboardSpace);
  }
  render() {
    var paddingTop = 110 - this.state.keyboardSpace /3;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.header,{paddingTop: paddingTop}]}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={require('image!pic1')} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.main}>
                <Text style={styles.joinNow}>Join Now</Text>
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.sub} >
                <Text style={styles.signin}>Sign In</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
             <Image style={styles.inputUsername} source={require('image!mail')}/>
             <TextInput
               style={styles.email}
               value={this.state.email} 
               placeholder="Email"/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
             <Image style={styles.inputPassword} source={require('image!locker')}/>
             <TextInput
               password={true}
               style={styles.email}
               value={this.state.password} 
               placeholder="Password"/>
          </View>
         <View>
             <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}>
             <Text style={styles.buttonText}>JOIN</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        </View>
        </View>
      )
  }
}
```

when i tried like this the padding show top of the view, but i want that the view to move upward when the keyboard as shown,can any one give me suggestions how to solve this,any help much appreciated